# OSX Mountain Lion - .profile doesn't do anything?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, homebrew, .profile

Recently tried the package manager Homebrew to grab things like PyQt4.  It also recommended grabbing Python; no problem, done.

So a simple `python` at the Terminal window didn't open the recently downloaded instance of Python, so I type `brew doctor` and it tells me this -

`Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:`

```
2to3
2to3-2.7
easy_install
easy_install-2.7
idle
idle2.7
pydoc
pydoc2.7
python
python-config
python2.7
python2.7-config
pythonw
pythonw2.7
smtpd.py
smtpd2.7.py
```

Consider amending your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin in your PATH.

Sure, no big deal - I google around and find out about editing `.profile` to establish paths.  I go to my home directory and enter `open .profile` - it doesn't exist.

No big deal, according to the Internet I can just create one here.  So that's fine, `touch .profile` works.  `open .profile` works.  I copy and paste a line from the Internet which puts `/usr/local/bin` ahead of the rest of the paths. Like so:

`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin"`

Save.  Try it.  Doesn't work.  I remove the double-quotes; no good. I add a colon to the end of the line, for some reason.  No good.

I google.  I see more information about `/etc/paths` but even after finding it and entering `sudo open paths` it seems I cannot unlock it.  And besides, most of the Internets also say that just adding a `.profile` file to my home directory ought to be enough and that I don't need to muck about with this.

But it hasn't been enough, and I'm still mucking about!  So what am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a .bash_profile?

Answer (score 0):

1. .profile file does not get reloaded automatically - it gets loaded on startup, or manually. Try opening terminal and issuing a `source ~/.profile`. Then try `set | grep PATH` to verify the PATH variable.
2. My .profile file does not contain quotes around the paths. Try removing them, saving the file and goto 1.

Comment: The quotes don't matter and the OP said they had already tried removing them.